# Access core-ajax response from within nested component?

Tags: polymer

I have a core-ajax element like so:

```
<core-ajax id="ds" auto url="address/to/data.json" response="{{data}}"></core-ajax>
```

Then a list element like so:

```
<my-items alarms="{{data}}"></my-items>
```

Which iterates through the data and displays it in another template:

```
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
    <my-item alarm="{{item}}"></my-item>
</template>
```

My question is, from within "my-item", how can I access the original {{data}}?  For instance, if I wanted to get a count of the total items in a javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass that information into `<my-item>`.

If `<my-item>` also published a `data` property, you could pass it like this:

```
<template repeat="{{alarm in alarms}}">
  <my-item alarm="{{alarm}}" data="{{alarms}}"></my-item>
</template>
```

or just the stats you need:

```
<my-item alarm="{{alarm}}" length="{{alarms.length}}"></my-item>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Polymer('my-item', {
  dataChanged: function (e) {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
});
```

that should give you the data you need

Comment: From his example, `data` is not a published property on my-item. `alarm` is.

Comment: it looks like i need to read things better. i didn't catch that ajax was feeding the element in question. i thought everything was in the my-item element. ill leave it to the pros from here.